# for any normal variety $X$ , is the coordinate ring $O(X)$ integrally closed?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Here varieties are irreducible.A variety $X$ is **normal** at a point $p \in X$ if $O_{p}$ is integrally closed.it is normal if it is normal at every point.($O_{p} $ is the ring of germs of regular functions on near $p$)

1. My question:for any normal variety $X$,is the ring of regular functions $O(X)$  integrally closed?

   I think it's true.here is my argument:Since $O_{p}$ is integrally closed for every point $p\in X$,note that $O(X)=\bigcap_{p}O_{p}$,the intersection of integrally closed domains is also integrally closed,so $O(X)$ is integrally closed.
2. Am I missing something? Is any wrong in my argument? Thanks in advanced!

Comment: By ring of regular functions do you mean the global sections? Or would you like to say $X$ is affine?

Comment: @leibnewtz Yeah, $O$ is indeed the sheaf of regular functions on $X$, $O(X)$ is the global section. Here the variety is any affine,quasi-affine,projective,or quasi-projective variety.

Comment: I think your argument is correct.

Comment: Lemma 6.38 of 'Algebraic Geometry' by Goertz/Wedhorn states that for a locally noetherian normal scheme $X$, any ring of sections is normal. So you do not have to restrict yourself to global sections.

Comment: @MooS got it!thank you!

Comment: You can also have a look at Liu's Proposition 4.1.5 in his book "algebraic geometry and arithmetic curves".